# RCP command handler not extend "org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler" class

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I am new to RCP trying to learn it through http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html#views but when i Defining commands and created the handler class it does not extend `org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler` class but it implements `IHandler` can any one tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us some of your code that isn't working?

Comment: as i am about to create the class when i click at hyper link "defaultHandler" in the class creation window so i had no code to share

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [handler extension point schema](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.ui/schema/handlers.exsd?view=markup), we have defined the handler as a class that implements IHanlder. So when you use the wizard by default it will add IHandler as the super interface. You have to add the AbstractHandler as a super class manually in that wizard.

Answer (score 1):

You doing everything right. You can extend your handler from AbstractHandler or IHandler. AbstractHandler is just adapter for IHandler

Answer (score 0):

I followed the same tutorial.
Initially , I used `IHandler` (It's given by the wizard itself)" and later and had overridden both the methods (`IShANDLED AND` is enabled ) to return `true`. But then, an exception is thrown, when I tried to run the command.
When I changed the interface to `AbstractHandler`, it started working..

Comment: This should be a comment.